# VS 2015, MVC Core, Right Click -> View In Browser not going to the chosen View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-mvc

In old days in ASP.Net class MVC, I can just Right click on the view and click on 'View in Browser' and I can go directly to the view...
for example, http://mysite/Home/RequestJob

However, in MVC Core, it's always opening http://mysite and it never goes to the View that I want to view directly.

Is there any setting I can change to get that feature back?  Am I missing something?

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Professional Version.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In MVC, it depends on the routing configured, so opening the view directly will show you nothing as the view depends on the controller and you can reach the controller through the route which is mapped to the URL.

Comment: Then why does the same feature work in MVC 5 in the same IDE, VS 2015?

Comment: Maybe they supported it back in 2015